# Polar plot in Matplotlib not centered

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

For some reasons, when I try to plot `(theta = 0, r = 0)` using the following code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.polar(0, 0, marker='x')
plt.show()
```

The point is not centered :

[image: polarplot with center]

I was able to reproduce this error multiple times on my computer and on Repl.it : [Link](https://repl.it/@damienlarocque/Matplotlib-polarplot-example)

So, how can I center the polar plot, so that the `x` shows in the center of it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "centered", but the radius starts at a negative value, something around `-0.04` in your case. Try setting `rmin` after you have plotted your point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot([0], [0], marker = 'x')
ax.set_rmax(5)
ax.set_rmin(0)
plt.show()
```

This gives a single little `x` exactly in the middle of the circle with radius `5`.

The problem usually does not appear if you plot multiple points with many interesting values, because it then sets the radius range to more sane defaults.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, you just have to set the limit of the `r` axis :

```
ax.set_rlim(0,2)
```

This gives the correct result

[image]